How to toggle Flutter Overflow border (yellow black lines)?
Is there a way to toggle the yellow and black banner shown in the image?  I know it's due to an overflow error, and I want to fix it. However, the banner obstructs my view, making it difficult to see what I'm doing. It's driving me crazy.
I have to run the app in release mode every time to see the effects of my customizations, and then switch back to debug mode for debugging because I need the Widget Inspector. Is there any way to toggle or suppress the black and yellow lines?
EDIT:
It's not about the code. I know there is a bug. I'm just wondering if there's a way to toggle or hide this banner for debugging purposes. I need to see what's behind the border to fix this issue.


Please share your code in which you have implemented this screen.

It's a rendering issue, you can either use a scrollable container or adjust your content size. Can you share the code for the widget that's causing the overflow error?

You could inspect the element from the DevTools. Hmm.

This only appear in debug where you miss something in bulding widget tree , so sized over flow, if you run it in release it won't appear

want to disable it for every widget and see the fact of overflowing only in the logs?

@pskink yes exectly

then find this mixin: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/main/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/debug_overflow_indicator.dart#L90 and you will see four hardcoded colors (Color(0xAARRGGBB)) - change AA to more transparent value or even 00 if you want - the downside is that you would need to do that each time you upgrade the flutter

@pskink although a good idea for my testing purpose it would be a good solution :D

btw i dont know why they did not add some global bool showOverflowIndicator in the framework which would control whether to show those lines or not

I don't think there is a way to disable this, but what you could do is wrap the widget in a OverflowBox so that this message does not appear and the widget can overflow.

Yeah, that's a nice workaround. Great idea. Thanks :D
